# In CPA, how does one-message security implies multi-message security?

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack

I am learning modern cryptography and recently we reached the CPA mechanism.

In CPA game setting, A sends two messages to C and then C randomly chooses one message and encrypts it and sent the encrypted text back to A, then A will determine which one of the two messages is chosen by C.

However, if A sends two identical messages, say 'm', to C, A would definitely know the encrypted 'm' by the returned text of C. Then, for the second time, A can send a 'm' and any other message to C, then, if the returned text of C is the same as that of the returned text when inputting 'm', the message chosen by C is 'm', otherwise is that any other message. And this enables A to have a probability of 1 to guess the chosen message of C.

So, it seems that one-message security doesn't imply multi-message security, even in the one-message security scheme, if the two sent messages from A are the same, A still has a probability of 1 to guess the chosen one of C.

Could anyone help me in understanding this?

Thank you for the answering!

Comment: If you send two identical messages, you will not learn anything new! So the advantage of the adversary doesn't change! CPA security requires randomized encryption, this is where the ECB fails. Actually once submitted the adversary has access to the Encryption oracle that is free in the public key cryptography.

Comment: My advice, read a proper book while learning these notations, The Prof Lindell's is fine. The devil in detail in Cryptography.

Comment: @kelalaka Thank you for the reply! I am thinking that we can send multiple times, each time with two messages, and for the first time, we send two identical messages 'm' to learn the encrypted text of 'm', but for the next times, we send 'm' with an arbitrary message, using this method we can get the encrypted message of the "arbitrary message".

Comment: There is no restriction to requesting the encryption of the same message from the encryption oracle. Consider the CBC mode, every time the message is encrypted with another nonce. Randomized encryption is required otherwise one can distinguish. Learning one of the encryption of the $m$ doesn't help you. There are $2^{128}$ for CBC mode, ofcource you will see same due to the collision bound...

Comment: Also, even the same $m$ you will fail 1/2 probability since you have to submit 0 or 1...

Comment: I see. So the key would be different every time for each pair of messages. Thank you!

Comment: The Key is fixed in the CPA game.

Comment: ... Fine, looks like it's really messy in my head, I will read the textbook.

Comment: I wrote a little one for you!

Comment: The main problem appears to be that you think that encryption could be deterministic. You have found the reason deterministic encryption can never achieve CPA security.

Comment: @Maeher Yes, that seems to be the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the CPA game, we play the following experiment

1. Generate a key $k$ with the security parameter $n$
2. The adversary $\mathcal{A}$ is given the $n$, Oracle access to the encryption oracle $Enc_k(\cdot)$
3. $\mathcal{A}$ outputs two messages $m_1$ and $m_2$ of the same length ( here, there is no restriction about $m_0 \neq m_1$)
4. A random bit is chosen $b \overset{R}\leftarrow \{0,1\}$ the the ciphertext $c = Enc_k(m_b)$ is computed and trasnmitted to $\mathcal{A}$. This is called **the challange ciphertext**.
5. $\mathcal{A}$ access to the encryption oracle $Enc_k(\cdot)$ ( even before  submitting)
6. And, finally, $\mathcal{A}$ submits $b'$ as their candidate
7. The output of the experiment is defined to be $1$ if $b' = b$ and $0$ otherwise. If the output is $1$, we also say that $\mathcal{A}$ succeeds.

Then we can make the definition of $Ind\text{-}CPA$ as;

An encryption scheme is  $Ind\text{-}CPA$ if for all probabilistic polynomial-time adversaries  $\mathcal{A}$ the advantage is negligible $negl(n)$

**Notes:**

1. The negligible is depends on the security parameter $n$
2. There is no restriction for submitting the same messages. The adversary must find the correct $b$.
3. If you send two identical messages there is no advantage since the adversary will not learn anything.
4. C**PA security requires randomized encryption. Deterministic encryption like ECB mode cannot have CPA security.**
5. The experiment also requires a good random number generator.
6. In public-key cryptography, the encryption oracle  $Enc_k(\cdot)$ is free. One can access all the time they have, consider encrypting with RSA's public key.
7. The key is fixed during the experiment (Step 1)

> However, if A sends two identical messages, say 'm', to C, A would definitely know the encrypted 'm' by the returned text of C. Then, for the second time, A can send a 'm' and any other message to C, then, if the returned text of C is the same as that of the returned text when inputting 'm', the message chosen by C is 'm', otherwise is that any other message. And this enables A to have a probability of 1 to guess the chosen message of C.

- You know the $m$ but which $b'$ will you submit to win the game?
- For the second time the encryption of the $m$ will change since the CPA game requires randomized encryption, in other terms **any CPA-secure encryption scheme must be probabilistic. In which, random coins tossed in order to ensure that two encryption of the same message is different.**

Comment: Thank you so much! It's really clear and helpful! I still need some time to digest these concepts. Now I found that I ignored the 'non-deterministic' and so many things else here. I am now reading the [lecture notes from Rafael Pass](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6830/2009fa/scribes/lecture11.pdf) and find it quite helpful. Thank you again.

Comment: Welcome to [crypto.se].

Comment: step 3, I assume it is m0 and m1, not m1 and m2 ?

Comment: @sitaram yes, thanks, let me correct that,

Comment: @kelalaka I would like to ask: suppose two ciphertexts have some relation such that we can know these ciphertexts are related to the same message. Then, does one-message secure also imply to multi-message secure ?